# Как в таблице выбрать сразу и номер строки и номер столбца с помощью this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть html таблицы:

```
<table>
<tr class="clickN Three"><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="clickN Two"><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class="clickN One"><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

В таблице нужно выбрать сразу и номер строки и номер столбца с помощью this. Когда делаю клик, чтобы было понятно, что кликнул по нужному столбцу и строку таблицы.
Написал такой код:

```
jQuery("tr.clickN").on("click",function(){
console.log( $(this).find("td").index() )
})
```

Выводится ноль (рассчитывал, что выводится индекс `td` нужного `tr`). Хотелось бы, чтобы вывелся индекс и номера столбца и номера строки (чтобы определить точную область клика)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery("td").on("click", function() {
    console.log($(this).parent().index(), $(this).index());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="clickN Three">
    <td>00</td>
    <td>01</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="clickN Two">
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="clickN One">
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```